# What datatype does the result of 2 concatenated char columns have?

Tags: oracle

Oracle docs says that 2 concatenated fields returns char type, but char type max length is the 2000 bytes.

In my case two columns have a char type, and length of each column 2000 bytes.

Example:

```
   create table temp(
      column_1 char(2000),
      column_2 char(2000)
   );

select column_1 || column_2 from temp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/operators003.htm):

> The result of concatenating two character strings is another character
>   string. **If both character strings are of datatype CHAR, the result has
>   datatype CHAR and is limited to 2000 characters.** If either string is of datatype VARCHAR2, 
>   the result has datatype VARCHAR2 and is limited to 4000 characters. If
>   either argument is a CLOB, the result is a temporary CLOB. Trailing
>   blanks in character strings are preserved by concatenation, regardless
>   of the datatypes of the string or CLOB.

So it means that when you will concatenate both the columns which have 2000 length then after concatenation it would be a CHAR type with length 2000 and the rest will be ignored.

Comment: if two columns have varchar2(4000) type, after concatenation, it also the rest will be ignored ? I'm confused

Comment: @user3555529:- No then it will not be ignored!

Comment: As i understood, ignoration will work when the columns have char datatype. Thank you!